# Android Progress bar not moving

Tags: android, progress-bar

I used below code for `ProgressBar` and it is working fine on Simple Activity but not in `ListView`, any one suggest me

Need Same as picture

[image: Sample Image]

got like this in listview

[image: Below code got this in listview]

Here is my code:

```
class StatsAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    LayoutInflater li;
    Context dctx;
    LinearLayout item;
    ProgressBar p;
    ObjectAnimator animation;
    public StatsAdapter(Context c) {
        this.dctx = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 10;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View view, ViewGroup arg2) {
        li = (LayoutInflater)dctx.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = li.inflate(R.layout.stats_listitem, null);
        item = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.item_layout);
        p = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        p.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.rgb(220, 41, 82), Mode.SRC_IN);
        animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(p, "progress", 16); 
        animation.setDuration(500); // 0.5 second
        animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        animation.start();
        //p.setProgress(50);
        if(arg0%2==1){
            item.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(252, 234, 238));
        }
        return view;
    }

}
```

Here is My XML:

```
   <ProgressBar
       android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
       style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="15dp" />
```

Comment: What type of animation do you want? Like and indeterminate progress?

Comment: Please see my edit question with image. and need fill animation from 0 position to 16 position

Comment: And what do you have at the moment? Probably you are not setting the Max value of the ProgressBar.

Comment: i set p.setMax(100); but not working

Comment: ProgressBar you are using in getview()??

Comment: Yes right inside getView()

Comment: Anything in the LogCat?

Comment: please see my edited question. and above code got that progressbar

Comment: Are you doing the animation in a click event? in onCreate method, onResume, where?

Comment: hey you need to show progress bar each item in your listview??

Comment: please see my edited question and added my BaseAdapter